# AddClass body tinymce by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'fb_add_tinymce' );
    function fb_add_tinymce() {
    global $typenow;
if( ! in_array( $typenow, array( 'post', 'page' ) ) )
    return ;
add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'my_tinymce_plugins');
}
function my_tinymce_plugins() {
$plugins_array = array(
    'columns' => get_template_directory_uri().'/editor_plugin.js'
);
return $plugins_array;
}
```

File editor_plugin.js:

```
( function() {
       $ = jQuery;
       $('#tinymce').addClass('abs');

 })();
```

This is not working :( Help me
I want to use js to add classes instead of php (not php)

Comment: I'm not sure your .js file is correct. But first, did you inspect your page to make sure the js file is loading?

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
editor = tinymce.get('#your_editor_id');
$(editor.getBody()).addClass('abc');
```